# Which aggregator scopes exist in ubuntu scope?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, scopes

I was thinking about developing an aggregator scope for ubuntu touch, but I can't find a list of some sort that shows which aggregator scopes are already available.
On the ubuntu website, they give a [list of keywords](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/scopes/guides/scope-keywords/), but I have no idea which keywords already have a scope and which don't.

Is there any way to find this out, or should I just start developing and hope for the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, arbitrary third party scopes in the store cannot be aggregator scopes. As aggregators can see the data returned by the results of any child scopes, it would be a privacy leak to allow arbitrary third party scopes to see that data, as they could do anything with it, and there could be private data returned.

Your scope can provide appropriate keywords, and it may be included by an aggregator scope. That is what the list of keywords is for.

Comment: So it is just not possible for me to write an aggregator scope? The only thing I can do is write a scope and make it reply to certain keywords in order for my results to be shown in an aggregator scopes provided by ubuntu?

Comment: Right. You could write an aggregator scope, but you could not put it in the official store, as it would need a security profile which presents a privacy risk.

Comment: That might also explain why I couldn't find any tutorial on how to write an aggregator scope ;)